# Cannot connect to the sandbox instance due to password authentication failure

Tags: greenplum

Hi~~ I'm doing the official tutorial from the [follwoing link](https://greenplum.org/gpdb-sandbox-tutorials/).

My system is windows 10, I'm using VirtualBox 6.0 and downloaded the latest sandbox.

The following are what I did step by setp:

(1) Boot up: I cannot upload image but the information on boot up are as follow:

`Hostname: gpdb-sandbox.localdomain
IP: 192.168.5.138
GPDB Admin: gpadmin
GPDB Password: pivotal
Tutorial User: gpuser 
Tutorial User Password: pivotal`

(2) Navigate to pg_hba.conf and add "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" to the last of it

(3) Navigate to postgresql.conf and add "listen_addresses = '*'" to it

(4) Then I loged in the OS and run the following commmand

`./start_all.sh`

(5) Then I opened a cmd.exe from my windows and run

`psql -U gpadmin -h 192.168.5.138 -p 5432 postgres`

(6) The program replies with request for password, then I typed in "pivotal"

And then the program replies with an authentication failure. Can anyone help me with that so that I can start the first step of the tutorial??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to type all the parameters if you are connecting to database from the sand box terminal.
just do psql and press enter you will be connected to gpadmin database.
if you changeor add any entries in pg_hba.conf please relode the configurations by running below command.

gpstop -u